# Adding a filename to log4j2 logger

Tags: log4j2

I am specifying the filename to log4j2 logger in the XML as below. All works fine but i get the error

> 2017-09-06 16:54:33,496 main ERROR Unknown object "RandomAccessFile" of type org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RandomAccessFileAppender is ignored: try nesting it inside one of: ["Appenders", "Loggers", "Properties", "Scripts", "CustomLevels"].

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration package="log4j.test" 
                   status="WARN">
        <Appenders>
            <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c %m%n"/>
            </Console>
        </Appenders>
       <RandomAccessFile  name="FILE" fileName="${sys:log4j.saveDirectory}/CMSAutomation.${date:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss}.log" append="true" immediateFlush="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}  %-6p  %C{1}.%t:%L  >>> %m%n"/>
        </RandomAccessFile >
        <Loggers>
            <Logger name="log4j.test.Log4jTest" level="debug">
                <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            </Logger>
            <Root level="trace">
                <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            </Root>
        </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is coming because `RandomAccessFile`  `appender` is not defined within `<Appenders>` XML element.

Below is the correct way of defining any `appender` including `RandomAccessFile` `appender` -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration package="log4j.test" 
               status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c %m%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RandomAccessFile  name="FILE" fileName="${sys:log4j.saveDirectory}/CMSAutomation.${date:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss}.log" append="true" immediateFlush="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}  %-6p  %C{1}.%t:%L  >>> %m%n"/>
        </RandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="log4j.test.Log4jTest" level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

You can check the same in log4j2 documentation [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/appenders.html#RandomAccessFileAppender).

Additional one point, you are not using `RandomAccessFile` appender in any `logger`. If you will not define it in any `logger`, it wouldn't work.